# Django: Filtering or displaying a model method in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with an expiration DateField.

I want to set up an Admin filter that will allow the user to toggle between "Not Expired" and "Any".

The model method is quite a simple Date comparison, no problem.

However assigning this as a field or filter parameter in the AdminForm is not automatic.

Is such a thing possible, and if not, what would be a wise work-around...

I would even be open to some sort of automated deletion of Expired rows, but I don't know how to start down that path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could include the model twice on the admin site by registering two `ModelAdmin` classes for it. You can override the `queryset()` method of the `ModelAdmin` to customize which instances are shown. Note that you need to define a model proxy and use that in the second `ModelAdmin` class, otherwise Django complains about registering the same model twice.

#### models.py

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    expired = models.DateField()

class ExpiredExampleModelProxy(ExampleModel):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = 'Expired Example'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Expired Examples'
```

#### admin.py

```
class NotExpiredExampleAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        return (super(ExampleAdmin, self).queryset(request)
                .filter(expiration__gte=date.today()))

class ExpiredExampleAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        return (super(ExampleAdmin, self).queryset(request)
                .filter(expiration__lt=date.today()))

admin.site.register(ExampleModel, NotExpiredExampleAdmin)
admin.site.register(ExpiredExampleModelProxy, ExpiredExampleAdmin)
```

Instead of customizing `ModelAdmin.queryset` you could also define custom managers for the models to get the same filtering outside admin as well.

See also

- [ticket 10712](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10712)
- [James Bennett's Xmas 2008 blog post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/)

Comment: I have model `X` with a proxy model `Y`, also model `A` with a proxy model `B`. `A` has a foreign key to `X`, and when somebody in the admin is editing `A`, it'll give them a little green plus sign to add a model `X`, or select one from the list. What I want is when they're editing proxy model `B`, I want that little plus sign to pop up the page to `X`'s proxy model `Y`. Is this possible?