# Django - How to make ModelAdmin classes show up in available permissions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I made a simple Django app.  I have one model "Visitor".  My goal is to have two two tables appear in the Django admin.  One with all of the visitors and one with only those for today.

I got everything working with the code below by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861897/django-filtering-or-displaying-a-model-method-in-django-admin). However my trouble is I can't get VisitorExpectedTodayProxy to show up in the "available permissions" when editing groups in the admin page.  Does anyone know how to do that?

**Models.py**

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    visit_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    visitor_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

#Make dummy models for different object views in admin interface
class VisitorExpectedTodayProxy(Visitor):
    class Meta:
        proxy=True
        verbose_name = "Visitor"
        verbose_name_plural = "Today's Visitors and Regular Visitors"
```

**Update:**

I did run syncdb but I'm still not seeing it on the admin site.  Results of syncdb:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
No fixtures found.

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.admin
 > south
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[I documented my hack to work around this here.](http://www.answermysearches.com/fixing-django-admin-permissions-not-getting-updated-after-adding-model-proxy/2236/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script I used to manually enter the ContentType entries for proxy objects, and then create new permissions for them.

This just generates the sql, which you should then run in mysql.  After that they should show up in the permissions list for the user, where they'll need to be added.  Some of the naming conventions for these are not obvious.

```
your_models=['proxy model',
            ]

for model in models:
    model_nospace = model.replace(' ','')
    sql = 'insert into django_content_type (name, app_label, model) values     ("%s","<<app_name>>","%s");'%(model,model_nospace)
    print sql
    for kind, permname in [('Can add','add_%s'%model_nospace),
                          ('Can change','change_%s'%model_nospace),
                          ('Can delete','delete_%s'%model_nospace),]:
        sql = 'insert into auth_permission (name, content_type_id, codename) values ("%s     %s",(select id from django_content_type where name="%s"),"%s");'%    (kind,model,model,permname)
        print sql
```

Comment: chnaged permname to lower case. if its not changed, appearing the permissions. but assigning them won't get any changes for me.

Comment: why create something that exists in django? `django.contrib.auth.management.create_permissions`

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question was closed a while ago, but I'm sharing what worked for me in case it might help others.

It turns out that even though permissions for the proxy models I created were listed under the parent apps after `syncdb`, and even though I granted my non-super user all permissions, it was still denied access to my proxy models through the admin.

Although I haven't tried the SQL based fixes above, fixing the bug at the Django level worked for me. You have to workaround a known Django bug (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154) and connect to the `post_syncdb` signal to properly create permissions for the proxy models. The code below is modified from https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2677/ per some of the comments on that thread.

I placed this in myapp/models.py that held my proxy models. Theoretically this can live in any of your `INSTALLED_APPS` after `django.contrib.contenttypes` because it needs to be loaded after the `update_contenttypes` handler is registered for the `post_syncdb` signal so we can disconnect it.

```
def create_proxy_permissions(app, created_models, verbosity, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates permissions for proxy models which are not created automatically
    by 'django.contrib.auth.management.create_permissions'.
    See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154
    Source: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2677/

    Since we can't rely on 'get_for_model' we must fallback to
    'get_by_natural_key'. However, this method doesn't automatically create
    missing 'ContentType' so we must ensure all the models' 'ContentType's are
    created before running this method. We do so by un-registering the
    'update_contenttypes' 'post_syncdb' signal and calling it in here just
    before doing everything.
    """
    update_contenttypes(app, created_models, verbosity, **kwargs)
    app_models = models.get_models(app)
    # The permissions we're looking for as (content_type, (codename, name))
    searched_perms = list()
    # The codenames and ctypes that should exist.
    ctypes = set()
    for model in app_models:
        opts = model._meta
        if opts.proxy:
            # Can't use 'get_for_model' here since it doesn't return
            # the correct 'ContentType' for proxy models.
            # See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17648
            app_label, model = opts.app_label, opts.object_name.lower()
            ctype = ContentType.objects.get_by_natural_key(app_label, model)
            ctypes.add(ctype)
            for perm in _get_all_permissions(opts, ctype):
                searched_perms.append((ctype, perm))

    # Find all the Permissions that have a content_type for a model we're
    # looking for. We don't need to check for codenames since we already have
    # a list of the ones we're going to create.
    all_perms = set(Permission.objects.filter(
        content_type__in=ctypes,
    ).values_list(
        "content_type", "codename"
    ))

    objs = [
        Permission(codename=codename, name=name, content_type=ctype)
        for ctype, (codename, name) in searched_perms
        if (ctype.pk, codename) not in all_perms
    ]
    Permission.objects.bulk_create(objs)
    if verbosity >= 2:
        for obj in objs:
            sys.stdout.write("Adding permission '%s'" % obj)


models.signals.post_syncdb.connect(create_proxy_permissions)
# See 'create_proxy_permissions' docstring to understand why we un-register
# this signal handler.
models.signals.post_syncdb.disconnect(update_contenttypes)
```

Comment: The question is not closed, its just having an accepted answer. Nevertheless better answer might change that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ./manage.py syncdb
```

Thats about it. It adds entries into auth_permission table.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix this is I dropped every table (deleting just the auth tables wasn't enough).  Then I commented out south from the installed apps in settings.py (not sure if that was causing problems).

Then I ran manage.py syncdb and everything is working now.

I just have to reload all of my data.  I'm still not sure how it got messed up in the first place.