# User permissions on proxy models in modeladmin

Tags: django, django-admin

When using a proxy model:

```
class Uf(models.Model):
...

class CustomUf(Uf):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class CustomUfAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

admin.site.register(CustomUf, CustomUfAdmin)
```

It seems like only superusers can access the CustomUf through admin site... I can't figure out how to grant permissions on CustomUf to regular users...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, Chris remark about content types gave me the hint...

I made the mistake to define the proxy object in "admin.py". This way, you have to be superadmin to access it.

If I define the proxy object in models.py, then the content type appears and everything works fine...

Comment: @Blaise Did you use South to manage the app? If so, you need to manually force South to trigger `post_syncdb`, check [here](http://dev.markhaus.com/blog/2011/04/django-admin-permissions-and-contenttype-table-doesnt-update-when-adding-proxy-models/)

Comment: Yes, this worked for me eventually. Had to get South to trigger the post_synchdb.

Comment: This worked for me in Django 1.3. Move the proxy model into models.py, re-run syncdb. New permissions!

Answer (score 4):

You need to run syncdb again so the new content types can be picked up.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's doesn't work... When I give superuser privileges to the user, he can access the CustomUfAdmin view, but without those privileges, it doesn't work...

Comment: If you're using South, this won't work because syncdb skips any South-managed apps.

Answer (score 4):

Please see this related Django issue: [#11154](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154)

You can overcome this by manually adding the rows to the 'auth_permission' table like:

```
INSERT INTO "auth_permission" ("name","content_type_id","codename") 
    VALUES ('Can add proxy model name',{content_type_id},'add_proxy_model_name');
```

Where content type id is the integer id of the relavent content type.

Comment: the accepted answer didn't work for me, but it's possible I screwed something up with appname/modelname.  This worked.

Comment: I made a script to manually do this here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486018/django-how-to-make-modeladmin-classes-show-up-in-available-permissions/20759563#20759563

Comment: This helped me when proxy model was in other app than base model. i.e. I defined base model in `app_a` and defined proxy model in `app_b` - django dodn't automatically create a content type and premissions for me.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question was closed a while ago, but I'm sharing what worked for me in case it might help others.

It turns out that even though permissions for the proxy models I created were listed under the parent apps, and even though I granted my non-super user all permissions, it was still denied access to my proxy models through the admin.

If you want to avoid [raw SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096980/user-permissions-on-proxy-models-in-modeladmin#answer-9891108) and script the fix in Python, you have to workaround a known Django bug (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154) and connect to the `post_syncdb` signal to properly create permissions for the proxy models. The code below is modified from https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2677/ per some of the comments on that thread.

I placed this in myapp/models.py that held my proxy models. Theoretically this can live in any of your `INSTALLED_APPS` after `django.contrib.contenttypes` because it needs to be loaded after the `update_contenttypes` handler is registered for the `post_syncdb` signal so we can disconnect it.

```
def create_proxy_permissions(app, created_models, verbosity, **kwargs):
    """
    Creates permissions for proxy models which are not created automatically
    by 'django.contrib.auth.management.create_permissions'.
    See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154
    Source: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2677/

    Since we can't rely on 'get_for_model' we must fallback to
    'get_by_natural_key'. However, this method doesn't automatically create
    missing 'ContentType' so we must ensure all the models' 'ContentType's are
    created before running this method. We do so by un-registering the
    'update_contenttypes' 'post_syncdb' signal and calling it in here just
    before doing everything.
    """
    update_contenttypes(app, created_models, verbosity, **kwargs)
    app_models = models.get_models(app)
    # The permissions we're looking for as (content_type, (codename, name))
    searched_perms = list()
    # The codenames and ctypes that should exist.
    ctypes = set()
    for model in app_models:
        opts = model._meta
        if opts.proxy:
            # Can't use 'get_for_model' here since it doesn't return
            # the correct 'ContentType' for proxy models.
            # See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17648
            app_label, model = opts.app_label, opts.object_name.lower()
            ctype = ContentType.objects.get_by_natural_key(app_label, model)
            ctypes.add(ctype)
            for perm in _get_all_permissions(opts, ctype):
                searched_perms.append((ctype, perm))

    # Find all the Permissions that have a content_type for a model we're
    # looking for. We don't need to check for codenames since we already have
    # a list of the ones we're going to create.
    all_perms = set(Permission.objects.filter(
        content_type__in=ctypes,
    ).values_list(
        "content_type", "codename"
    ))

    objs = [
        Permission(codename=codename, name=name, content_type=ctype)
        for ctype, (codename, name) in searched_perms
        if (ctype.pk, codename) not in all_perms
    ]
    Permission.objects.bulk_create(objs)
    if verbosity >= 2:
        for obj in objs:
            sys.stdout.write("Adding permission '%s'" % obj)


models.signals.post_syncdb.connect(create_proxy_permissions)
# See 'create_proxy_permissions' docstring to understand why we un-register
# this signal handler.
models.signals.post_syncdb.disconnect(update_contenttypes)
```