# Django admin: User permissions for proxy model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I created an App which models are only proxymodels, inherriting from Models of another app.
Now I have the problem, that I can't give users the Permissions to edit these models via the admininterface.

In the Users app of the Adminpage, where I normally can grant and revoke permissions for a specific app, this app isn't even listed.
I already tried `syncdb` but this didn't help me.

The answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096980/user-permissions-on-proxy-models-in-modeladmin) SO thread didn't help me, too

**EDIT**
I just tried to create a new Model (inside of the app, which only containts proxymodels).
For this model, it was possible to grant permissions.

Of course, since proxymodels use the same Data as their parent models, no additional permissions should be needed, if the user is allowed to change the parent model.  But each time I try to access this model it says "Forbidden"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096980/user-permissions-on-proxy-models-in-modeladmin and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037642/django-proxy-model-permissions-do-not-appear - this is a known Django issue (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11154).

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Proxy models before but I think you might need to set them separate, but in any case I think what you should try is backing up your database by running this line

```
python manage.py dumpdata your_app --all > /home/you/your_project/backup.json
```

Then reset that Model

```
python manage.py dumpdata reset your_app
```

Once that is done load your data again

```
python manage.py loaddata your_app /home/you/your_project/backup.json
```

See if that fixes the glitches on your project

Answer (score 0):

in my case i did something similar to you, i added a Proxy Model for User, and couldn't get the relevant permissions to show up in the  permisssions tab. 
Doing a manage.py makemigrations & manage.py migrate fixed it, it includes the relevant fields in the contenttype table or something like that.